# What CSS rule would cause elements within a div to overlap when height is applied to the parent div?

Tags: html, css

As per the title, I have a parent div within which are div (contains image), h4, and h5 elements. When I apply a height to the parent div the elements overlap. See images below for illustration. Note: the elements are overlapping with other elements from OTHER divs.

[image][image]

As I have purchased the template I'm not certain what is causing this. I have tried turning rules on and off in Chrome dev mode to no success.

Comment: The pictures might have a transparent background. Is that the case?

Comment: @LajosArpad that is correct, yes

Comment: Can you edit your question with the relevant part of your structure and CSS? A Fiddle would be very helpful.

Comment: @LajosArpad I've removed `height: 100%` from the div that contains the img which has fixed the issue. Cheers for your interest.

Comment: I am happy you managed to resolve your problem. I would like to kindly ask you to answer your question then. You will be able to accept your own answer in two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I removed `height: 100%` from

```
<div>
    <div class="remove-height-attribute">
        <img>
    </div>
    <h4></h4>
    <h5></h5>
    <p></p>
<div
```